# How to Inject Generic Repository(Or Business Logic Layer) Into ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, dependency-injection, blazor

For simplicity sake, I'd like to Inject a generic repository into a view model. I'm add the the ViewModel and Repository to the services collection and the ViewModel depends on the Repository. From what I've read, the ViewModel's constructor parameters should be resolved automatically, since it's using IConfiguration. I've tried explicitly instantiating the ViewModel in the `Services`, but still get the same runtime error and seems to defeat the purpose as I'm creating another instance of the repository.

Repository/IRepository look like this

```
    public class Repository<TPoco, TDatabaseConnection> : IRepository<TPoco, TDatabaseConnection>
            where TPoco : class
            where TDatabaseConnection : IDbConnection, new()
    {

        public Repository(IConfiguration configuration, string connectionName = "DefaultConnection" )//SqlConnectionConfiguration configuration) //(string connectionString)
        {
            _connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString(connectionName);
            _configuration = configuration;
        }


...
```

View Model

```
    public class PersonViewModel
    {
        private IRepository<Person, IDbConnection> _PersonRepository;

        public List<Person> Persons { get; set; }

        public PersonViewModel(IRepository<Person, IDbConnection> personRepository)
        {
            _PersonRepository=personRepository;
        }
...
```

In Startup.cs file I add the services like so:

```
    services.AddScoped<IRepository<Person, SQLiteConnection>, Repository<Person, SQLiteConnection>>();
    services.AddScoped<PersonViewModel>();  //runtime errors here
```

I'm getting two runtime errors (`System.AggregateException`)

```
Inner Exception 1:
InvalidOperationException: Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: BlazorInjection.ViewModels.PersonViewModel Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: BlazorInjection.ViewModels.PersonViewModel': Unable to resolve service for type 'DapperRepository.IRepository`2[BlazorInjection.Models.Person,System.Data.IDbConnection]' while attempting to activate 'BlazorInjection.ViewModels.PersonViewModel'.

Inner Exception 2:
InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'DapperRepository.IRepository`2[BlazorInjection.Models.Person,System.Data.IDbConnection]' while attempting to activate 'BlazorInjection.ViewModels.PersonViewModel'.
```

Am I missing a concept? How do I correct this?

Comment: This may help https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/asp-net-core-dependency-injection-how-to-register-generic-types

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change class structure to:

```
public class PersonViewModel
{
    private IRepository<Person> _PersonRepository;

    public List<Person> Persons { get; set; }

    public PersonViewModel(IRepository<Person> personRepository)
    {
        _PersonRepository = personRepository;
    }
}

public interface IDbConnection
{

}

public class Person { }


public interface IRepository<TPoco> { }

public class SQLiteConnection : IDbConnection 
{
    private string _connectionString;
    private IConfiguration _configuration;

    public SQLiteConnection(IConfiguration configuration, string connectionStringName)
    {
        _connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString(connectionStringName);
        _configuration = configuration;
    }
}

public class Repository<TPoco> : IRepository<TPoco>
    where TPoco : class
{
    public IDbConnection Connection { get; }

    public Repository(IDbConnection connection)
    {
        Connection = connection;
    }
}
```

And than in `Startup.cs` simply change to

```
services.AddScoped<IDbConnection>(sp => ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<SQLiteConnection>(sp, "defaultConnectionStringName"));
        services.AddScoped(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(Repository<>));
        services.AddScoped<PersonViewModel>();
```

Notice generic repository registration which makes it easy to extend your data layer. `ActivatorUtilities` allows you to combine current scope `container` services with custom parameters. This way (one generic, injected connection) is also in my opinion better from the design perspective, as your repository clients do not need to know the underlying database implementation.

Comment: I tried that. I get this error about implicit conversion: `There is no implicit reference conversion from 'DapperRepository.Repository<BlazorInjection.Models.Person, System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection>' to 'DapperRepository.IRepository<BlazorInjection.Models.Person, System.Data.IDbConnection>'.`  Does System.Data.SQLiteConnection not implement IDbConnection?

Comment: Tried that too. Similar error. It's asking for the parameter, so I did this. `services.AddScoped<IRepository<Person, IDbConnection>>(sp => new Repository<Person, SQLiteConnection>(Configuration));`  I get two errors: `CS1662 Cannot convert lambda expression to intended delegate type because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type` and second one asking for an explicit cast.hmm ?

Comment: Is there any reason why you need repository to be double generic? If not you could take IDbConnection as a constructor parameter

Comment: I was having my repository instantiate the dbconnection. I suppose it's not necessary. I can try to pass it in as a parameter

Comment: please see revised answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227460/discussion-between-damian-and-gismofx).